# ASP.NET MVC6: Setting webroot programmatically

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC6 static files are served from `wwwroot` by default.

The directory `wwwroot` is defined in `project.json` by the key `webroot` (as documented here: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html)

I am wondering if it is possible to set this `webroot` at runtime (at startup) programmatically.

I would like to switch `webroot` at runtime depending on running in debug or production mode. Since my static assests (JS, CSS ...) are processed at build time (concatenation, minification ...) I figure it is the best approach to have a directory with the source assets and a directory that contains the optimized assets (build output).

At runtime I would like to point `webroot` to the optimized assets when running in production mode.

Has anybody figured out how to set `webroot` programmatically?

**Update 2015-11-19:** In my scenario I would like to use static files only. As pointed out in an answer, switching between different assets can be realized with TagHelpers (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2015/08/06/a-complete-guide-to-the-mvc-6-tag-helpers.aspx) when using server-side rendering of the html with Razor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation describes how to set up static file serving from any directory.](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html)

The solution for my problem was to switch the directory from which to serve static files based on the hosting environment like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    private IHostingEnvironment env;
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        this.env = env;
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            var webRootPath = env.WebRootPath;
            var webSrcPath = webRootPath + @"\..\wwwsrc";
            app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(webSrcPath),
                RequestPath = new PathString("")
            });
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(webSrcPath),
                RequestPath = new PathString("")
            });
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles(); // use wwwroot
        }
    }
```

With this setup I can place all my frontend assets (html, javascript, css) in `wwwsrc` and serve them unprocessed during development from that directory.

My frontend build (based on gulp) then processes the assets in `wwwsrc` and puts the optimized assets (concatenated, minimized, revisioned and references adjusted in the html) in `wwwroot`.

If I want to test the release build, I can serve from `wwwroot`.

Switching between debug and release build can be accomplished by setting the environment variable `ASPNET_ENV` in the Debug profile (Project -> Properties -> Debug or in the file `Properties/launchSettings.json`).

Thanks to @Maxime Rouiller for pointing me into the right direction in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would go a different way.

First, when you F5 your application, it automatically set the `ASPNET_ENV` to `Development`. In Razor, you can then use TagHelpers to switch your resources like this :

```
<environment names="Development">            
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site1.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site2.css" />
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-file-version="true"/>
</environment>
```

This will allow you to change your resources/javascript or even HTML based on which environment your are actually running on.

The only thing missing is to set the `ASPNET_ENV` on your Staging and Production machine and it will automatically be picked up. No need to change the `wwwroot` dynamically.

If you really want to stick to changing the `wwwroot`, for me it would be a deployment task rather than a *at runtime* step.

Otherwise, [check the documentation](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html) on Static Files which you already linked. It provides code examples on how to link at runtime on different folders. Maybe the thing you are missing is a dependency on `IHostingEnvironment` which would provide you with Environment variables to decide on which environment you are.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the tag helpers that help to render the html on the erver side differently at runtime depending on the environment. But in my scenario I am not using Razor/server side rendering at all, I would like to work just with static filles... (I updated the question accordingly)